# How to normalize users' response times to questions?

Tags: normalization, time-varying-covariate

A group of users is given a set of 18 simple questions of two types in random order. From many experiments, I know that the response time decreases roughly exponentially. Following is a typical response time example

[image: decreasing response time]

What is the best approach to test whether one question type requires more reaction time than another?

I have one idea which I will describe as an answer suggestion to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion.
First, we need to model the response time as a function of the question number. It looks like a simple linear model will do.

Next, we will analyze the residuals between the actual and the fitted response timings. If the two question types require the same amount of time, the distributions of the two types of residuals should be the same.